# How to fix white space behind navbar

Tags: jquery, css, animation

so, I've beed trying to make a navbar animation, something like unfolding paper. The problem is that behind the navbar there is no color (body color) and I'd like for that small part to be the same color as the navbar when the animation runs, without setting the body color the same color as the navbar.

```
transform: skewX(-40deg) rotateX(40deg);
```

becomes:

```
transform: transform: skewX(0deg) rotateX(0deg) !important;
```

To better understand the problem, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jz403ca9/1/), open and close it and you'll most likely see the problem. Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe I'm misinterpreting the question, why not just make an empty div behind the navbar with the same background color?

Comment: Yep, it worked, sorry for the stupid question. Thanks!